# PHP form: How can I solve a 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: php, forms

I've build a contact form on my project, but I get 500 Internet Server Error when I examine my script. I show my code below, so please give me some tips.

Thank you.

form: permission (705)

```
<form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="mail.php" >
            <div>
            <label for="name">氏名<span>必須</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" size="50" name="name" id="name" class="text" class="required" value="" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="company">社名</label><br />
                <input type="text" size="50" name="company" id="comany" class="text" value="" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="pref">住所<span>必須</span></label><br />
                <select name="pref" size="1" id="pref">
                    <option value="selected">都道府県</option>
                    <option value="北海道">北海道</option>
                    <option value="青森県">青森県</option>
                    <option value="岩手県">岩手県</option>
                    <option value="宮城県">宮城県</option>
                    <option value="秋田県">秋田県</option>
                    <option value="山形県">山形県</option>
                    <option value="福島県">福島県</option>
                    <option value="茨城県">茨城県</option>
                    <option value="栃木県">栃木県</option>
                    <option value="群馬県">群馬県</option>
                    <option value="埼玉県">埼玉県</option>
                    <option value="千葉県">千葉県</option>
                    <option value="東京都">東京都</option>
                    <option value="神奈川県">神奈川県</option>
                    <option value="新潟県">新潟県</option>
                    <option value="富山県">富山県</option>
                    <option value="石川県">石川県</option>
                    <option value="福井県">福井県</option>
                    <option value="山梨県">山梨県</option>
                    <option value="長野県">長野県</option>
                    <option value="岐阜県">岐阜県</option>
                    <option value="静岡県">静岡県</option>
                    <option value="愛知県">愛知県</option>
                    <option value="三重県">三重県</option>
                    <option value="滋賀県">滋賀県</option>
                    <option value="京都府">京都府</option>
                    <option value="大阪府">大阪府</option>
                    <option value="兵庫県">兵庫県</option>
                    <option value="奈良県">奈良県</option>
                    <option value="和歌山県">和歌山県</option>
                    <option value="鳥取県">鳥取県</option>
                    <option value="島根県">島根県</option>
                    <option value="岡山県">岡山県</option>
                    <option value="広島県">広島県</option>
                    <option value="山口県">山口県</option>
                    <option value="徳島県">徳島県</option>
                    <option value="香川県">香川県</option>
                    <option value="愛媛県">愛媛県</option>
                    <option value="高知県">高知県</option>
                    <option value="福岡県">福岡県</option>
                    <option value="佐賀県">佐賀県</option>
                    <option value="長崎県">長崎県</option>
                    <option value="熊本県">熊本県</option>
                    <option value="大分県">大分県</option>
                    <option value="宮崎県">宮崎県</option>
                    <option value="鹿児島県">鹿児島県</option>
                    <option value="沖縄県">沖縄県</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="city">市区町村群（番地含む）<span>必須</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" size="50" name="city" id="city" class="text" value="" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="apart">アパート／マンション名（部屋番号含む）</label><br />
                <input type="text" size="50" name="apart" id="apart" class="text" value="" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="email">メールアドレス<span>必須</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email" class="text" value="" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="tel">電話番号<span>必須</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" size="50" name="tel" id="tel" class="text" value="" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="message">内容</label><br />
                <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" class="text" id="message">
</textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="送信" name="submit" />
        </form>
```

mail.php: permission (705)

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$pref = $_POST['pref'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$apart = $_POST['apart'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = "氏名: $name \n\n 社名: $company \n\n 住所: $pref \n $city \n $apart \n\n $email \n\n $tel \n\n $message";
$recipient = 'yawatajyuku@gmail.com';
$subject = '八幡宿っていいねに関する問い合わせ';
$mailheader ='From $email"
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo 'ご送信ありがとうございます！担当からの連絡をお待ちください。'; // true -> show up thanks.
?>
```

Comment: that's an Apache error not a php one.

Comment: Look in the server's error logs - details about 500 errors go in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

> $mailheader ='From $email"

Should be like this:

> $mailheader = "From $email";

You have to match quotes quotes when enclosing text,

> ' does not match "

You also forgot the semicolon ; at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

On your $mailheader line in mail.php, replace the single quote (') with a double quote (").

Answer (score 0):

in the line:

```
$mailheader = 'From $email"
```

you start with a single apostrophe and you end with a double and there is no semi-colon at the end.